# Pushing values into a temporary container for aggregation and comparison in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, aggregation, temp-tables

Postgres 11.5 & 11.7.

I've got a strategy question I'm hoping for some direction with. I'm building up a series of scores and methods. From there, I'd like to be able to find the min, max, and average of the scores. And, of those, I'd like to get the name of the method that produced the best score.

Here's a sample query, using `pg_similarity` and a custom version of `monge_elkan`. But that's totally unrelated to the question, it's an example of "how do I push sets of values into *something* for aggregation and comparison?" Sounds like a CTE, but I'm not sure how to create it in this case.

```
WITH
basic_scores AS (
          select monge_elkan('1 West Extra King Ret.','Tray Extra King Plush') AS monge_elkan_score,
          sqrt(monge_elkan('1 West Extra King Ret.','Tray Extra King Plush'))  AS monge_elkan_quad_score,

          jaccard('1 West Extra King Ret.','Tray Extra King Plush')            AS jaccard_coefficient,
          jaccard('1 West Extra King Ret.','Tray Extra King Plush') * 0.3      AS jaccard_handicap,

          qgram('1 West Extra King Ret.','Tray Extra King Plush')              AS qgram_score,
          similarity('1 West Extra King Ret.','Tray Extra King Plush')         AS trigram_score,
          word_similarity('1 West Extra King Ret.','Tray Extra King Plush')    AS word_score,

          lev('1 West Extra King Ret.','Tray Extra King Plush')                AS levenshtein_distance,
          jaro('1 West Extra King Ret.','Tray Extra King Plush')               AS jaro_distance,
          jarowinkler('1 West Extra King Ret.','Tray Extra King Plush')        AS jaro_winkler_distance
),

extended_scores AS (
select  monge_elkan_score::float8,
        (monge_elkan_score - jaccard_handicap)::float8 AS monge_elkan_handicap_score,
        monge_elkan_quad_score::float8,
        (monge_elkan_quad_score - jaccard_handicap)::float8 AS monge_elkan_quad_handicap_score,           

        jaccard_coefficient,
        jaccard_handicap,

        qgram_score::float8,
        trigram_score::float8,
        word_score::float8,

        levenshtein_distance::float8,
        jaro_distance::float8,
        jaro_winkler_distance::float8

  from basic_scores)

select 

greatest(monge_elkan_score, monge_elkan_handicap_score, monge_elkan_quad_score, monge_elkan_quad_handicap_score,           
qgram_score, trigram_score, word_score, levenshtein_distance, jaro_distance, jaro_winkler_distance),

least(monge_elkan_score, monge_elkan_handicap_score, monge_elkan_quad_score, monge_elkan_quad_handicap_score,           
qgram_score, trigram_score, word_score, levenshtein_distance, jaro_distance, jaro_winkler_distance),

* from extended_scores
```

Manually pivoted, here's the output:

```
greatest                          0.80829036
least                             0.34375
monge_elkan_score                 0.653333306
monge_elkan_handicap_score        0.567619021
monge_elkan_quad_score            0.80829036
monge_elkan_quad_handicap_score   0.722576074
jaccard_coefficient               0.285714286
jaccard_handicap                  0.085714286
qgram_score                       0.425531915
trigram_score                     0.34375
word_score                        0.5
levenshtein_distance              0.5
jaro_distance                     0.672438672
jaro_winkler_distance             0.672438672
```

The winner, in this case is `monge_elkan_quad_score`, with the value `0.80829036`. I can sort that out with a ginormous `CASE`, but there must be a nicer way. I'm not expecting anyone to write me the code, but a bit of pseudo-code to push me in the right direction would be great. I thought of

- An array with elements of `['measure',score]`, like `['monge_elkan_score',0.653333306]`, and so on. This, I do not know how to write in SQL.
- A temporary table....but something in my mind things they're slow and/or expensive?
- Is it simpler to build it out in PL/PgSQL? Working with arrays is not so hard here.
- Or is there another way to build a temporary result that I can then query?

Thanks for suggestions.